# MonoGame crash trying to load font from .xnb file

Tags: xna, windows, monogame, fonts

My MonoGame project uses a pre-compiled .xnb file to load a sprite font, and it works fine on Windows XP. The .xnb file is marked as content and copied to the output directory.

I've copied the project across to a machine running Windows 7, and now the game crashes when I try to load the sprite font. There is no exception thrown. The application just exits with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).

Both machines have MonoGame 3.0 installed. The Windows XP box (where the game works) also has XNA 4.0.

I can't remember exactly how I generated the .xnb file! I originally just took it from the output of an XNA project, but when I switched from MonoGame 2.5 to 3.0, I remember having some issues with it and tried to use the MonoGame content pipeline instead. So my .xnb file could be from either method.

How can I work out why spritefont loading is failing?

Comment: What do you mean you copied the project across? Did you rebuild the project on Windows 7 or just copy the contents of the Debug directory?

Comment: I rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the application error in Windows Event Viewer, I could see that the error occurred in nvoglv32.DLL, which is an Nvidia dll.

Upgrading my drivers fixed the problem.